# Does std::stack expose iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, stack

Does the `std::stack` in the C++ STL expose any iterators of the underlying container or should I use that container directly?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Stack does not have iterators, by definition of stack. If you need stack with iterators, you'll need to implement it yourself on top of other container (std::list, std::vector, etc).
[Stack doc is here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

P.S. According to a comment i got from Iraimbilanja, std::stack by default uses std::deque for implementation.

Comment: +1. note also that std::stack by default uses std::deque as its implementation so this might be a good choice for the default implementation of an iterstack as well. Another question is, *why* do you want an iterable stack and not, say, a straight deque

Answer (score 14):

If you need a stack with iterators, you have two choices:

- `std::vector` using `push_back()`, `pop_back()`.
- `std::deque` with either `push_back()`/`pop_back()` or `push_front()`/`pop_front()`.

Answer (score 9):

The `std::stack` does expose its underlying container (and therefore iterators) to *subclasses* through its protected interface. The `std::stack`'s underlying container object corresponds to the (protected) data member `c`.
So if you want to access them, you could extend `std::stack` a little.

```
template<typename T, typename Container = std::deque<T>>
class iterable_stack
: public std::stack<T, Container>
{
    using std::stack<T, Container>::c;

public:

    // expose just the iterators of the underlying container
    auto begin() { return std::begin(c); }
    auto end() { return std::end(c); }

    auto begin() const { return std::begin(c); }
    auto end() const { return std::end(c); }
};

int main()
{
    iterable_stack<int> st;

    st.push(2);
    st.push(5);
    st.push(3);
    st.push(7);
    st.push(9);

    for(auto i: st)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
2 5 3 7 9
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to figure out how to use the ::c ... without succeed yet.
Could you explain a little bit how can we manage to get an iterator on Stack by using the ::c ? I saw that it is "linked" to container_type, but my thoughts are not clear right now. An explanation of ::c would really help ! Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Stumbling over here lately I'd rather drop the non-const `begin` and `end` – *modifying* the stack via iterators should rather *not* be allowed...

Answer (score 2):

In [SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stack.html), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9sh48d5.aspx) and [GNU](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00530.html) documentations, `stack` doesn't provide an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Yor are asking

> Does std::stack expose iterators?

Many people gave answers. If my English would be better, I would maybe also understand the exact meaning of 'expose'.

If we are referring to the STL and the class std::stack and the pre defined functions defined herein, the answer is NO.

My guess would be that you are asking, because you want to have iterators.

So, if we go one step further, we have the function top(). And top() can be interpreted as a dereferenced iterator. With that, we can easily define Iterators to stack elements. The memory of the stack is guaranteed to be contiguous.

See below. We are defining and using iterators for std::copy:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

using Number = int;
using UnderlyingContainer = std::vector<Number>;
using Stack = std::stack< Number, UnderlyingContainer>;

using StackIterator = const Number *;

std::istringstream testData("5 8 1 4 9 3");

int main()
{
    // Put the test data onto the stack
    Stack stack{ UnderlyingContainer {std::istream_iterator<Number>(testData),std::istream_iterator<Number>()} };

    // Print the test data
    // Get iterators
    StackIterator end = &stack.top() + 1;
    StackIterator begin = end - stack.size();

    if (not stack.empty())
        std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<Number>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

So you can create iterators for a stack. But, caveat:

The std::stack intentionally hides its elements under the hood. So, if you write-access the data, I would see it as a design fault. Read-access through const pointers/iterators is for me OK. But maybe you should better use a std::vector . . .