# How to traverse stack in C++?

Tags: c++, stack, traversal

Is it possible to traverse `std::stack` in C++?

Traversing using following method is not applicable. Because `std::stack` has no member `end`.

```
std::stack<int> foo;

// ..

for (__typeof(foo.begin()) it = foo.begin(); it != foo.end();  it++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That´s why it is a "stack". Last in first out, that´s it (theoretically).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does std::stack expose iterators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525365/does-stdstack-expose-iterators)

Comment: You've chosen the wrong data type. Don't use a stack if you want to be able to iterate over it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Is it possible to traverse std::stack in C++?

No. A stack is a data structure you should use when you are interested in placing elements on top and getting elements from the top. If you want an iterable stack, either use a different data structure for a stack role (`std::vector`?) or write one yourself.

Answer (score 15):

It is not possible to directly traverse an `std:: stack` as it does not have an `end` member and that's how a stack data-structure is supposed to be i.e. only have one pointer. But, still here are two lazy hacks to traverse it:

### 1) Loop Based:

```
while(!st.empty()) {
        cout << st.top();
        st.pop();
    }
```

Problems with the loop-based approach:

- The original stack gets empty.

### 2) Recursion Based:

```
template <typename T>
void traverse_stack(stack<T> & st) {
    if(st.empty())
        return;
    T x = st.top();
    cout << x << " ";
    st.pop();
    traverse_stack(st);
    st.push(x);
}
```

Advantages of Recursion based approach:

- Maintains the original stack elements.

Problems with Recursion based approach:

- Maintains an internal stack.
- May fail for large size of the stack.

Comment: For loop based, you can always push the elements you're popping from the original stack onto another stack. Then once you're done iterating, drain the other stack onto your original stack, maintaining the original state. Basically doing the same thing you've done in the recursive based solution with the call stack.

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned you need printing for debugging purposes, maybe something like this would work for you:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
void StackDebug(std::stack<T> s)
{
    std::vector<T> debugVector = std::vector<T>();
    while (!s.empty( ) )
    {
        T t = s.top( );
        debugVector.push_back(t);
        s.pop( );
    }

    // stack, read from top down, is reversed relative to its creation (from bot to top)
    std::reverse(debugVector.begin(), debugVector.end());
    for(const auto& it : debugVector)
    {
        std::cout << it << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::stack< int > numbers;
    numbers.push( 9 );
    numbers.push( 11 );

    StackDebug(numbers);
}
```

Output is, as expected, "9 11"

Comment: Someone down-voted this because stacks are not suposed to use like this. But you said it's for debugging purposes, and you are right. Developers must act right in production, but for testing sometimes is necessary break some default behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

I **don't** think that it is possible to traverse through a [stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack). The best I can think of is using vector using `std::vector` using `push_back(), pop_back()`

The stack does not provide a begin or end member function so you cannot use it with a [range based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) which requires both.

In your case it would be better to choose some other data structure if you really want to iterate through it.

Answer (score 2):

One can write a simple wrapper over STL's `std::stack` and iterate over the underlying container since, quoting from the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack#:%7E:text=The%20container%20must%20satisfy%20the%20requirements%20of%20SequenceContainer):

> The container must satisfy the requirements of SequenceContainer

This container is accessible via the **protected member** `c`, so something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/35Yezhjqv) should probably work for your case:

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T, typename Container = std::deque<T>>
struct DebugStack : private std::stack<T, Container> {
    auto& push(T& elem) {
        std::stack<T>::push(elem);
        return *this;
    }
    auto& push(T&& elem) {
        std::stack<T>::push(elem);
        return *this;
    }
    auto& pop() {
        std::stack<T>::pop();
        return *this;
    }
    T top() {
        return std::stack<T>::top();
    }
    void print() {
        auto const& container = std::stack<T>::c;
        //T should be printable
        std::copy(begin(container), end(container), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout<<'\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        DebugStack<int> stack;
        stack.push(1).push(2).push(3).push(4);
        stack.print();
        stack.pop().pop().pop();
        stack.print();
    }

    {
        DebugStack<std::string> stack;
        stack.push("First").push("Second").push("Third").push("Fourth");
        stack.print();
        stack.pop().pop().pop();
        stack.print();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 
1 
First Second Third Fourth 
First
```

One can change the `auto` return type to `DebugStack` (as in [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7zedqxETr)) to make this solution work with `C++11` since auto deduction of return types was introduced with [`C++14`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto#:%7E:text=(since%20C++14)%20in%20the%20return%20type%20of%20a%20function&text=The%20return%20type%20is%20deduced%20from%20the%20operand%20of%20its&text=return%20statement).

Comment: This looks very cool. What is the earliest version of C++ this will work on?

Comment: @user1857492 Updated my answer to include the C++ version info. It can be made to work with C++11 without changing much.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do this, but you can get a stack values without popping with pointer casting, this makes some assumptions about how the compiled class is stored in memory, not a good idea in general.

As long as you don't change the default underlying container which is `std::deque`, you can:

```
std::stack<int>s;
s.push(1234);
s.push(789);

std::deque<int>* d;
d = (std::deque<int>*)&s;
cout << (*d)[0] << endl;
cout << (*d)[1] << endl;
```

output without popping the stack:

```
1234
789
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't traverse through stack. Stacks are a type of container adaptor, specifically designed to operate in a *LIFO* context (last-in first-out), where elements are inserted and extracted only from one end of the container. Elements are pushed/popped from the "back" of the specific container, which is known as the top of the stack. It is not intended for stack to show this behavior, for this we have other containers

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stack>

using std::stack;    

stack< int > numbers;
numbers.push( 1 );
numbers.push( 2 );

while ( not numbers.empty( ) )
{
    int number = numbers.top( );
    numbers.pop( );
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Comment: That changes/empties the stack. What I originally wanted was just traverse the stack and print it for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::deque if you want to implement LIFO concept and be able to iterate at the same time.
To emulate stack, use push_front(), front(), pop_front()

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

Internally deque is a sequence of "individually allocated fixed-size arrays", so works significantly better for large amounts of data than stack but worse than vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
        stack<int> s,dbg; //s = not what's supposed to be

        while(!s.empty()) {
            cout << s.top() << " "; //print top of stack
            dbg.push(s.top());      //push s.top() on a debug stack
            s.pop();                //pop top off of s
        }

        //pop all elements of dbg back into stack as they were
        while(!dbg.empty()) {
            s.push(dbg.top());
            dbg.pop();
        }
```

I just had to do this to check out what the heck was going wrong with stack on a Leetcode problem. Obviously in the real world it probably makes more sense to just use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Since `c++` stack doesn't have some kind of iterator
this is a basic stack with iterators.

**MutantStack.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <stack>

template <class T>
class MutantStack : public std::stack<T>
{
public:
    typedef typename std::stack<T>::container_type::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename std::stack<T>::container_type::const_iterator const_iterator;

    MutantStack(void) {}

    iterator begin(void)
    {
        return this->c.begin();
    }

    iterator end(void)
    {
        return this->c.end();
    }

    const_iterator cbegin(void) const
    {
        return this->c.cbegin();
    }

    const_iterator cend(void) const
    {
        return this->c.cend();
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do a for loop:

```cpp
for (stack<T> newStack = stack; !newStack.empty(); newStack.pop()){
   T item = newStack.top();
}
```

Comment: I see a syntax error here! Also, the OP was looking for a solution that doesn't pop everything out.