# Topological sorting of DAG in C++; data structure for storing the sorted list?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, depth-first-search, topological-sort

I implemented a topological sorting of a directed acyclic graph in C++ that outputs a topological sorted list.

I see some implementations where the sorted list is stored in `std::stack`, and some in `std::vector`. I am not sure which or some other data structure would be the most appropriate for my case. Essentially, I just need to loop through this sorted list, and extract the elements stored from top to bottom. The list is not modified during the extraction process.

Using a `std::vector` seems to be a waste, time-complexity-wise, since I'll be reallocating the vector every time a new element is added to the list. This list can get pretty massive.

It seems that I cannot loop through `std::stack` according to [How to traverse stack in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194548/how-to-traverse-stack-in-c).

Is there another option that would be more appropriate for what I want to do?

Comment: Pre-allocate space in the `vector` using `reserve`.

Comment: ah, but what about in situations where I have no clue (or even a rough idea) how large the vector should be? I work which lists that could be on the order of billions, but granted, they are usually ints.

Comment: But you do know how many nodes are in your DAG? Because that's the size you need for the list.

Comment: No, sometimes I may not know. That's why I posed the previous question. Most times I do know how many nodes, so I can obviously then reserve the list with the known number of nodes.

Comment: If you need to iterate through it once, and in order from start to end, you can use queue. But I think that performance-wise vector is your best option, although it may seem unintuitive. This summary of standard containers in STL may help you out to decide:

http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-summary.html

Comment: Thanks. Actually I will iterate through it many times.