# Does Stack have iterators in C++?

Tags: c++

From what I know, stack does not have iterators in C++. For example, this post ([Does std::stack expose iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525365/does-stdstack-expose-iterators)) explicitly states that stack does not have iterators. However, I was told by my supervisor that stack in c++ should have iterators since it is a standard data structure and you can do stack.begin() (However, from what I know, there's no such syntax in standard C++). How do I convince him? Why stack does not have iterators in C++?

Question#2: Thank you all for awesome answers. I think the question now comes down to: why doesn't it make sense to have iterators for stack?

Comment: Just take a look at the documentation ...http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/ Is there iterator ? Nop. begin() ? Nop.

Answer (score 6):

You can convince your supervisor by advising your supervisor go and read section 23.6.5 of ISO/IEC-14882(2011), the specification for `std::stack`.

`std::stack` does not have iterators.

Comment: He might also mention to the supervisor that the STL’s functionality is generally super-punctiliously specified (as this answers’ citation suggests) and so how any part of it “should” behave is, unlike (say) Markdown or PHP, exempt from opinionated subjectivity.

Answer (score 3):

`std::stack` provides a strictly last-in-first-out view of the underlying container, and that's the point of it: to restrict the use of the underlying container to LIFO.

And so it does not provide iteration.

However, it does provide the underlying container as a `protected` member, which means that it's designed for being derived from. In your derived class you can provide iterators, and whatever you want. Also it's possible to just access that `protected` member of an ordinary `std::stack`, even without using any cast (namely via implicit conversion of member data pointer).

Re the added 2<sup>nd</sup> question,

> **”** why doesn't it make sense to have iterators for stack?

It can make sense, but in most cases it would provide the non-LIFO access that `std::stack` is designed to remove, i.e. in most cases it would be at odds with the very purpose of `std::stack`.

For debugging, one's debugger will show the contents of a `std::stack`, so there's no big need to have direct support for doing it in code.

---

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

namespace cppx {
    using std::stack;

    namespace hack {
        template< class Item >
        auto container_of( stack<Item> const& st )
            -> typename stack<Item>::container_type const&
        {
            struct Hacked: stack<Item> { using stack<Item>::c; };
            return st.*&Hacked::c;
        }
    }  // namespace hack

    template< class Item >
    auto begin( stack<Item> const& st )
    { return hack::container_of( st ).begin(); }

    template< class Item >
    auto end( stack<Item> const& st )
    { return hack::container_of( st ).end(); }

}  // namespace cppx    

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using namespace std;

    stack<int> st;
    for( int const x : {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 4} )
    {
        st.push( x );
    }

    using cppx::begin; using cppx::end;
    for( auto it = begin( st ); it != end( st ); ++it )
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Since in this example `begin` and `end` are not placed in namespace `std`, a range based loop would not compile.

I didn't do that because the legality (validity) of specializing a standard function for a standard container, in namespace `std`, is an issue I don't want to get into here. I think it's not permitted, although specializing for one's own type would be OK. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Does it always do so by standard? I thought STL containers were not designed to be subclassed.

Comment: @bipll: Yes, the standard requires the protected member. And no, it's not true that STL containers are not designed to be derived from. `std::stack` is main counter-example.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf do you happen to know why the “don’t derive from STL containers” notion is so strongly held – are there any actually pitfalls in doing it in practice?

Comment: @fish2000: I think it's tied in with an ungood practice to delete via a pointer to the base class. That would be Undefined Behavior since the destructor isn't virtual.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf aha that is a handy caveat then; one should not assume the base destructors are virtual when one is STL-deriving. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

`std::stack` is but a container adapter. It accepts a type of container (`std::deque` by default) as template parameter, and an instance of `stack` can be constructed from an instance of this container, but otherwise the underlying private container is not exposed and the stack itself does not have iteration facilities.